# Query de Mongoose siempre me devuelve un array vacío

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy usando una base de datos que se llama Products. El esquema es este:

```
const mongoose = require("../utils/mongoAtlas");


const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
});

const productModel = mongoose.model("product", productSchema, "Products");

module.exports = productModel;
```

Hago una simple query de:

```
const productSchema = require("./productsSchema");
const getProductsGreaterThan = async (minimum_id) => {
try{
    console.log(minimum_id);
    const productById = await productSchema.find({id: {$gt:minimum_id}});
    return productById
}
catch(err){
    console.error(err);
}
```

}

En controllers tengo esto puesto:

```
if (req.params.minimum_id) {
        const productsById = await productsModel.getProductsGreaterThan(req.params.minimum_id);
        res.status(200).json(productsById);
    }
```

Y usando esta ruta en teoría me debería devolver los productos con un id mayor que el que le introduzco por req.params...

```
routes.get("/products/:minimum_id?",productRoutes.getProductsGreaterThan);
```

Pues resulta que al poner esta url => http://localhost:3000/products/10 Me devuelve un array vacío. En que puedo estar fallando? Para otras queries como find({}) si me lo devuelve bien...

Comment: Hay muchas cosas extrañas en tu código. ¿Qué versión de Mongoose utilizas? ¿De dónde sacas `landingSchema` en la definición del modelo? ¿Porqué usas un schema para las consultas (`find`)?

Comment: Lo de landing schema ha sido un error, lo he editado. En el código estaba bien.  El esquema es simplemente orientativo, para que se entienda lo que hay en la base de datos. En cuanto a la versión de mongoose, utilizo la 6.2.10.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que `req.params.minimum_id` existe? Ya que, aunque sigo sin comprender parte de tu código (los nombres Schemas, Models no tienen un uso lógico), es probable que el valor de `req.params.minimum_id` sea `undefined`, lo cual produce un resultado `[]` al realizar la consulta. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado.

Comment: Así es, tengo un console.log que me chiva lo que req.params.minimum_id me da...